# How to refresh Azure AD admin roles on local computer?

Tags: windows, entra-id

My organization is using Azure AD and lately my user account privileges have changed from a normal user to a global administrator.

On some computers though I do not have administrator access when I login. The user information does not seem to be up to date. When running `whoami /groups` I do not see an entry `BUILTIN\Administrators` as on other computers.

I have tried restarting, but the user information is not refreshed. How can I force a refresh, so I have admin privileges on these computers?

Answer (score 0):

The "Domain Admins" group is added when you join the computer to your domain. There is no *refresh* happening. You need to manually re-add the group to the "BUILTIN\Administrators" group. Or via script or GPO.

Comment: Is this possible without local admin rights?

Comment: If you do not have access to a local admin user, you can use a group policy to add that user.